# Delete all lines after a certain number of lines

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I truncate after 1000 lines in a csv file? The goal is to keep only the first 1000 lines in the file and delete all others.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017994/how-do-i-limit-or-truncate-text-file-by-number-of-lines

Comment: 1000 lines or 1000 rows? They are not the same thing, because cells can contain line breaks in CSV.

Comment: @aff: Self-answering is not only allowed but encouraged. In fact, there is a text field in the Question form that allows you to write the answer and the question at the same time.

Comment: … [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.105375619.1202364740.1596038209-1245021112.1698860860) … So, those who know will refine  it and those who don’t know will be informed … In moderation of course.

Comment: @aff This is by no means a new trend.  New users post things they think are "new posts" all the time and then we go through and close them on review.  No new trend, just more observed.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `head -n <n>` to print first `n` lines:

```bash
head -n 1000 "file.csv"
```

To write to a file use a redirection:

```bash
head -n 1000 "file.csv" > "some_other_file.csv"
```

To overwrite the same file, you need to write to a temporary file first and then overwrite the original file ...

```bash
head -n 1000 "file.csv" > "file.csv.tmp" && mv "file.csv.tmp" "file.csv"
# or more safe use mktemp
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
head -n 1000 "file.csv" > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" "file.csv"
```

... or use `sponge` (part of `moreutils` --> `sudo apt install moreutils`)

```bash
head -n 1000 "file.csv" | sponge "file.csv"
```

Other (non-portable) options to edit the file in place using GNU versions of `sed` and `awk`:

```bash
sed -i 1000q "file.csv"
# or
sed -n -i '1,1000p' "file.csv"
# or
sed -i '1001,$d' "file.csv"
# or
awk -i inplace 'NR>1000{exit}1' "file.csv"
```

Comment: Note that all `sed` implementations have the `-i` option, it's just that some _require_ an extension, and some require a space between the `-i` and the extension while others require no space. So the `sed` is almost portable. However, perl's -`i` operator is entirely portable (and is, I think, where `sed` got the idea anyway) so you can do `perl -pi 'print if $. < 1001' file`.

Comment: Also note that if you're going to use `awk -i`, you'd better be sure there's no file named `inplace` or `inplace.awk` in the current directory: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749646/70524

Comment: @terdon You probably meant something with `-n` instead `perl -i -ne 'print if $. < 1001' file`

Comment: Ugh, sorry! No, I meant something with `-p` but without `print`, like this: `perl -pi 'exit if $. > 1000' file`. Thanks, @Raffa.

Comment: @terdon I see … that is even more efficient  … But an `-e` is most likely going to be needed on Ubuntu or else `perl` might look for a script file instead of a string script I think.

Comment: Oh man... I should stick to writing answers, I don't do comments well. Not on Ubuntu @Raffa, everywhere. I meant `perl -i -pe 'exit if $. > 1000' file` but I'm an idiot. Thanks!

Comment: @terdon LOL :D … You cold be anything but that last word … I know you know it but probably focused on the script itself rather than how to run it because it's not a big deal for you and you would make it run if you wanted by hook or by crook without breaking a sweat  … My comments were intended to educate the audience and not you because you’re well educated already (you knew that)  :-)

Answer (score 6):

In terminal run:

```
head -n 1000 /path/to/file.csv
```

To have the result in a separate file, run:

```
head -n 1000 /path/to/file.csv > /path/to/new_file_with_first_1000_linces.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX standard utility for **ed**iting files is the [`ed` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html), and you can use it like this:

```sh
ed file.csv <<-HERE
  ,1000w
  q
HERE
```

`ed file.csv` starts the `ed` utility and opens the file `file.csv` for editing. `ed` is intended to be used interactively, so the way it works is that you type commands into `ed` and `ed` then executes those commands.

However, we want to use this in a script, not interactively, so we use a [*Here-Document*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04), which allows us to re-direct stdin as-if we had typed in those commands ourselves.

Commands in `ed` are typically of the form *address one-letter*.

The first command in our `ed` script is `,1000w`. The address here is an address range: `,1000` which is the same as `1,1000` meaning "all lines from 1 to 1000". The command is `w`, which is the *write* command. The write command takes an optional filename argument, but if you don't supply one, it takes the last used file, which is what we want.

The second command is just the *quit* command.

So, what this script is telling `ed` is to `w` write the first 1000 lines back to the file, then `q`uit. The end result is exactly what you want: truncate the input file to 1000 lines.

But beware! 1000 lines does not mean 1000 rows! [A CSV file can contain line breaks within cells](https://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.html#page-3), for example, this CSV has two lines but only one row:

```csv
"Cell #1","Cell
#2"
```

If your actual goal is to select the first 1000 *rows*, then you will need to parse the CSV file with a CSV parser. For example using a [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) script like the following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv

with open("file.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = [row for row in reader][:1000]

with open("file.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep only the first 1000 lines:

```
sed '1000q' file.csv
```

To write to a new file:

```
sed '1000q' file.csv > new_file.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it’s CSV, use miller:

```
miller —-csv head -n 1000 file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR>1000{exit} 1' input.csv > output.csv
```

This will print the input lines unchanged (the seemingly stray `1`), but once the internal line counter exceeds 1000, it will exit processing.

Assuming you have an `awk` implementation that understands the `-i inplace` extension, you can omit the redirection to a temporary output file and have `awk` modify the input file directly:

```
awk -i inplace 'FNR>1000{exit} 1' input.csv
```

Comment: [As with the other answer using awk -i](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492645/delete-all-lines-after-a-certain-number-of-lines#comment2615004_1492649),  note that if you're going to use `awk -i`, you'd better be sure there's no file named `inplace` or `inplace.awk` in the current directory: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749646/70524

Comment: @muru Oops, missed that one :(